# Why does the "git index" have so many names?

Tags: git, git-index, git-stage

While reading how to use Git, I found a lot of different names for `git index`.

They were:

- `directory cache`
- `current directory cache`
- `staging files`
- `staging area`

How come there are so many options to name exactly one thing?

How I should to name it to not to confuse my future interlocutors whose backgrounds I do not know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, the most commonly used term is `Staging Area`.

---

**Evidence:**

- Files and folders are referred to as `Staged` and `Unstaged` in the Git system when performing `git` commands.
- From what I've observed: Most developers only read the [Getting Started - Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) documentation when first starting out with Git. This document refers to it as the `Staging Area`.
- As someone who works a lot with Git and often surrounded by people who work a lot with it to, most developers I've met refer to it as the `Staging Area`.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Harmelodic ... the term "Staging area" is probably most used and straight-forward.

For example, when using the `git-add` command, you can say that you are "staging" content.

The term `index` was used early on in Git's development but it was changed.

[This](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Consistent-terminology-cached-staged-index-td6021438.html) is a good historical thread.

Snippits:

> Commands that pay attention to the registered content of files rather 
>   than the copies in the work tree use the option name "--cached".  This
>   is mostly for historical reasons --- early on, it was not obvious that
>   making the index not match the worktree was going to be useful.

...

> "cache" was an old name (and still established name in-use in the
>   code)  for the index...cached to mean "look only at what is recorded
>   in the index".

...

> Originally, the way to say "what is in the current working tree for
>   this  path is what I want to have in the next commit" was
>   "update-index".  "What  I want to have in the next commit" is "the
>   index", and the operation is  about "updating" that "What I want to
>   have...", so the name of the command  made perfect sense. 
>   "update-index" had a safety valve to prevent careless  invocation of
>   "update-index *" to add all the cruft in the working tree  (there
>   wasn't any .gitignore mechanism in the Porcelain nor in the  plumbing)
>   and by default affected only the paths that are already in the  index.
>   You needed to say "update-index --add" to include paths that are  not
>   in the index.
>
> A more user friendly Porcelain "git add" was later implemented in
>   terms of  "update-index --add", but originally it was to add new
>   paths; updating the  contents was still done via "update-index"
>   interface.

...

> In short, "stage" is an unessential synonym that came much later

Answer (score 3):

With Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), the documentation is now clearer regarding "index" synonyms based on "**`cache`**": they are **obsolete** and purged from said documentation.

See [commit b356d23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b356d236389979f8c65ee76562d44acc62efdc46) (08 Jan 2021) by [Utku Gultopu (`ugultopu`)](https://github.com/ugultopu).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit eecc5f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eecc5f0775ebbd454f92e1da02f83bc43b5f3703), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b356d236389979f8c65ee76562d44acc62efdc46): remove "directory cache" from man pages
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Utku Gultopu</sup>

> **"directory cache" (or "directory cache index", "cache") are obsolete terms which have been superseded by "index".**
> Keeping them in the documentation may be a source of confusion.
> This commit replaces them with the current term, "index", on man pages.

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b356d236389979f8c65ee76562d44acc62efdc46/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L26-L27):

> This merges the file listing in the index with the actual working
> directory list, and shows different combinations of the two.

`git update-index` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b356d236389979f8c65ee76562d44acc62efdc46/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L33-L34):

> Modifies the index.
> Each file mentioned is updated into the index and
> any 'unmerged' or 'needs updating' state is cleared.